# What does this code do in ns2?

Tags: c++, ns2

So i have a code in ns2:

```
ibin=((param1<<ilevel)+param2)%hash_bins_
```

hash_bins_ is a fixed integer value. param1 and param2 are src and dest address of a packet in ns2 that is obtained by the code below.

```
hdr_ip* iph=hdr_ip::access(pkt);
param1=(int)(iph->saddr());
param2=(int)(iph->daddr());
```

ilevel is just a `for` loop parameter  that changes from 0 to 1 ,2, etc. lets take a value of ilevel to be 2, what does the code for ibin do? give me an example if possible by inserting random values for param1 and param2.

Comment: This is C++ code, not Tcl.

Comment: shifts the source address 2 positions, adds it to destination address and computes the remainder against hash_bits. Example with random values: param1=0; param2=0; --> ibin=0